# apache permanent redirect all requests to another port

Tags: apache, redirect

How to configure Apache to redirect all requests from port 80 to a port 8080? For example http://google.com.localhost must redirect to a http://google.com.localhost:8080 but for all requests.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName proxy.localhost
ServerAlias *.localhost

Redirect permanent / *:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You mean for all possible host names? I don’t think there is any variable substitution available with the Redirect directive. Use mod_rewrite instead, in a RewriteRule you can access env variables such as the request host name.

Comment: And don't use a permanent redirect until you understand what it does and what you are applying it to.

Comment: @CBroe, yeah, I mean for all possible hosts (google, facebook, twitter, ....)

Comment: @symcbean, changed it to ProxyPass

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Redirect` for this, because `Redirect` does not allow for variables.

Inspired by the examples using `mod_rewrite` from the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

Note that you need `mod_rewrite` enabled for this to work.